# Is it possible to style a Views 'group by' field that's excluded from display?

Tags: theming, views

I'm working on a glossary view. I have created letter headers by rewriting a copy of the term title, limiting it to 1 character, excluding it from display, and using that as the "Group By" field. The field is then shown by Views, but it doesn't contain the `<h2>` tag that I wrapped around the field in the rewrite rules. The normal term titles are output (by default) with `<h3>` tags. I would like the letter headers to be larger, but since Views seems to be overriding everything, I can't see how to do accomplish this.  It doesn't even output the class name I attached to the field.

Any ideas?  Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the advanced tab you can see what templates you need to override the views template. Copy the templates mentioned from the modules/views/themes folder to you own theme/templates folder, rename them as the view suggests under advanced and style your output.

note: if you display a teaser or full node, but forced it to use fields, the styling (making it h3) won't work.

The h3 is coded in views-view-unformatted-list.tpl.php. The $title there is output of the field you grouped by. There you can set it to h2.

UPDATE: 
This is the default views template for outputting lists (the container which contains all rows as a group). This one is named views-view-unformatted.tpl.php, you need to rename it to match with your view.

```
 <?php

/**
 * @file
 * Default simple view template to display a list of rows.
 *
 * @ingroup views_templates
 */
?>
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3> // THIS IS THE GROUPNAME
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?> // THESE ARE THE ROWS INSIDE THE GROUP
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If you want to put style on ALL the rows inside the group then you can use the view-ui itself, or use the template called views-view-fields.tpl.php to override all rows.

If you want to style ONE specific row use views-view-field.tpl.php (note there is no 's' behind field).

Comment: Wouldn't that display every title as an H2, instead of just the grouping field? I tried copying views-view-field.tpl.php and naming it views-view-field--glossary--title-1.tpl.php (the View and field names), but the only thing in that template is `<?php print $output; ?>`

Comment: No I make an answer of it and you will see